# AWS - Alexa directive definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm sorry for asking this, but, in a simple way, what is an **Alexa directive**?

I failed on try to find something clear.

Comment: Hi Deivison! Make sure you go through this document first: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/video-skills-multimodal-devices/understand-directives-and-responses.html
If something is unclear, gives us more details so we can help

Comment: Hi i've looked at this documentation before, but i'm needing a simple definition for directives, something like "directives are commands sent from AVS to Lambda etc.." in a clear way.

Answer (score 1):

Think of directive as an object response that withholds relevant information about that specific directive in a format that Alexa understands and knows how to interpret it. For example, if you want to send an APL document to Alexa, you should use 'Alexa.Presentation.APL.RenderDocument' directive type along with the  the document itself as part of your response. Alexa will receive the json response and will know how to render it.

Here is a sample of APL directive response:

```
"response": {
  "directives": [
    {
      "type": "Alexa.Presentation.APL.RenderDocument",
      "document": {
        "type": "APL",
        "version": "1.0",
        "theme": "dark",
        "import": [],
        "resources": [
            ...
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
...
```